# Running time-series regressions on a dataset with large gaps: is it legitimate?

Tags: regression, time-series, dataset, econometrics

I would like to run a plain-vanilla time-series regression, to estimate the sensitivity of my dependent variable to a set of explanatory variables.

However, instead of running the regression on the entire time-series, I would like to running it only over specific time periods, all stacked together as one continuous dataset. For example, a time-series of stock returns could be subdivided into a bull market subset and a bear market subset. I would like to run the regression over  bull-market periods only, or bear market periods only.

The issue is that these market conditions (regimes) are discontinuous. In other words, you have a time period of bull market, followed by one of bear market, then bull, then bear,...
The discontinuity between two bull market periods or two bear periods could be several years.

Is it legitimate to stack all the subsets of the same regime, e.g. bull, and run the regression? The purpose is to get a regime-specific sensitivity to the explanatory variables.

Comment: Depending on your model, there is a logic to this in so far as the different subseries could be considered as realisations of the same generating process. Depending on your data, I would guess wildly that this won't work well because of side-effects of the subseries not joining smoothly. Aren't bull and bear both nonstationary any way (not my field at all; correct my ignorance)?

Comment: You've answered that. Will they join without looking ridiculous? remains my very simple main question.

Comment: The concept behind regimes is that non-stationary time series, such as market data, shift through different “modes” during which market behavior and dynamics are different. In other words, stock behave differently in a bull vs. bear market, but behave somewhat in a similar fashion within similar regimes. So the data is non-stationary across-regimes, but would be stationary within each specific regime. Wouldn't it? So I think joining different subsets of bull regimes would make sense. I am still not fully convinced. What do you think?

Comment: I can't add to my previous comments. I just pitched in to say something simple because the question has been ignored otherwise. You still don't address what I identified as my main question. Just drawing a graph should tell you if it's too weird to work.